# Angular 2:Not able to get a token in another component which is stored in local storege

Tags: html, web-services, angular, typescript

I have one application which include login and home component,

login.service.ts

```
  let body = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log("logged in user",body);
    return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/user/authenticate', body, { headers: contentHeaders })
    .map(res => res.json())

    .map((res) => {
        var token1:any = res;
        console.log(token1);
        if (token1.success) {
          localStorage.setItem('auth_token', token1.token);
          this.LoggedIn = true;
        }

        return res.success;
      });
}
isLoggedIn() {

    return this.LoggedIn;
  }
```

in this service i am getting token in variable token1 and isLogged method contain

```
constructor(private _http: Http) {
  this.LoggedIn = !!localStorage.getItem('auth_token'); }
```

Login.component.ts

```
login(event, username, password) 
   {

    this.loginService.login(username, password)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        alert("login successfull");
      },
       error => {
          alert(error.text());
          console.log(error.text());
        }
    );
```

From this login i can able to authenticate and and its routing to home component,

Home.serice.ts

```
getClientList()
   {
     let headers = new Headers();
     headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     let authToken = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
     headers.append('X-auth-Token', 'authToken')
      return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/client/list?isClient=Y', {headers})
      .map(res => res.json())
   }
```

Home.component.ts

```
 onTestGet()
    { 
          this._httpService.getClientList()
          .subscribe(
            data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => alert(error),
             () => console.log("finished")


     );
  }
```

now question is how can i access that token in home component which is in token1 varible(login) i have tired to getitem token.but i am getting token null.please anybody help me.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
localStorage.getItem('auth_token')
```

This should work, but you are getting null, because lifecycle of the data different.

I suggest you to use Subject construction for this purpose, especially you already have service with data.

Example:

```
loginInfo$ = new Subject();
private _logininfo = null;
getLoginData () {
    if(!_logininfo) {
         this.http..... { this._loginInfo = data; 
                          this.loginInfo$.next(data); }
         return this.loginInfo$.first()
    }
    else return Observable.of(this._logininfo);
}
```

So now, your service at the same time storage of data and handler for missing login.

Comment: yes i have tired in home.service.ts in getclientList() method,but i cannot able to access token.

Comment: @PramodRamadand if you are using getClientList at the moment when itme is yet was not put into storage, then it is null. You can add some debug info into question: console.log(token1); and console.log(authToken) in getClientLIst?